# Crossplatform css for scrolls bars

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am getting super frustrated here, not being able to design a simple scroll bar that has a simple color and thickness and display that on different browsers and smartphone devices.

Is there any resources that are able to get me through this.

One of my issues is that the below horizental scroll bar looks super skinny on my andriod phone and I would like to have the same thickness/height and colors on smart phones

Here is my example

```
 <div class="chartWrapper">
        <div class="chartAreaWrapper scroll-color-colors" id="chartAreaWrapper">
                   <div style="width:1000px; height 450px">
                   scrollable content
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css code

```
@media (max-width: 1600px) {
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 430px;
}

.chart {
  width: 700px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 420px;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow: scroll;  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:40px; /*This Works*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background-color: #a7cb11;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px; /*This do not work*/
}

.scroll-color-colors {
  scrollbar-color: #a7cb11 white;
}
```

}

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0cxe8yw/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the height in this part of the code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:40px; /*This Works*/
  height: 20px; /*This PROBABLY work*/

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work on the computer or phone? Cause i tested in computer and all ok!
https://jsfiddle.net/pL1buz92/1/

Comment: It works fine on chrome, but not on a smart phone or firefox, i believe the same goes safari

Comment: I believe custom scrollbars are not supported in Firefox or IE/Edge.
I found this site that shows how you can use css webkit in different mobile and navigators, hope it helps you: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar

Comment: Thank you Silvia
I found out a way to make it work on Firefox. I think I'm just missing safari